# How to implement a java equivalent for WaitForMultipleObjects windows API?

Tags: java, concurrency

We need to have a cleanup thread that will do cleanup repeatedly. The cleanup will be triggered

1. after a specified time period or
2. after a specified event

In Windows we have:

```
DWORD WINAPI WaitForMultipleObjects(
  _In_       DWORD  nCount,
  _In_ const HANDLE *lpHandles,
  _In_       BOOL   bWaitAll,
  _In_       DWORD  dwMilliseconds
);
```

...which will wait for specific events for specified time. The wait will be released when any of the specified event occurs or when the time-out occurs.

Do we have a similar implementation in Java? I tried the CountDownLatch and CyclicBarrier. CountDownLatch cannot be reset again, so couldn't use that and CyclicBarrier has some dependency on the number of threads. Looking for something better than CyclicBarrier. Will Timer and TimerTask help?

Comment: If you were able to use WaitForMultipleObjects, would you be passing true or false for `bWaitAll`?

Comment: We will be waiting for one of the event to occur. So we will be passing false for bWaitAll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Multiple implementations are provided in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Your event producers could put events into the queue.

Your cleanup thread could poll for an event, with a timeout, with the method [`BlockingQueue.poll( long timeout, TimeUnit unit )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Comment: Thank you. Will try this solution now.

Comment: Thank you @Andy Thomas. BlockingQueue works fine for this requirement. We are also trying with TimerTask and Timer. TimerTask and Timer seems to be cleaner. The task is simple that we don't have to use ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. Our only concern is that it should not hold the system resources. Which one would you prefer? BlockingQueue or the TimerTask and Timer. Thanks again.